# Sitecore 7 Lucene.Net.Contrib highlight search results

Tags: c#, sitecore, lucene.net, highlighting, sitecore7

I am trying to do highlighting on the search results. Here is the relevant part of my code.

```
QueryScorer scorer = new QueryScorer(q);
Lucene.Net.Search.Highlight.IFormatter formatter = new SimpleHTMLFormatter("<b>", "</b>");
Lucene.Net.Search.Highlight.Highlighter highlighter = new Highlighter(formatter, scorer);
highlighter.TextFragmenter = new SimpleFragmenter(800);
Lucene.Net.Util.Version vers = new Lucene.Net.Util.Version();
vers = Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30;
TokenStream stream = new StandardAnalyzer(vers).TokenStream(string.Empty, new StringReader(text));

string s = string.Empty;
try
{
    s = highlighter.GetBestFragments(stream, text, 10, "...");
}
```

Here, GetBestFragments method throws a System.MissingMethodException. 
I have tried to replace the original Lucene.net dll with Lucene.Net.Contrib but this time, I dont know what I should write instead of TokenStream. It doesnt exist in Lucene.Net.Contrib.* dlls.

I am working on existing code and I need to find out how I can rewrite TokenStream class and GetBestFragments method.

Thanx

Comment: When you say replace lucene.net with lucene.net.contrib... I think you still need a reference to both?

Comment: some earlier posts might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20331760/sitecore-7-highlight-search-results

Comment: @remco : This was also posted by me. The information in that post brought me to that point

Comment: @EngelbertCoder do you have a reference to both lucene.net with lucene.net.contrib...

Comment: @geedubb I have reference to both dlls but lucene.net was the old incompatible dll that comes with sitecore7. And the problem was about the deployment process, that somehow the new lucene.net was replaced by the old one. I have corrected that. Now it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was something about deployment, that the new compatible Lucene.dll was replaced by the incompatible Sitecore7 dll.

So, if both lucene.net and lucene.net.contrib dll are referenced, it should work.

Not directly the solution to my question, but this source is worth mentioning again. (About lucene.dll versions) : http://laubplusco.net/sitecore-7-lucen-3-0-highlighted-results/